# How to move message to Trash folder using IMAP?

Tags: ios, xcode, imap, mailcore2

Spent hell lot of time to find a proper way to move or delete messages but didn't found any. Every email service acts different. Please help =(

When I try to perform "set delete flag > expunge"...

- **aol.com** and **outlook.com** - email just disappears without being copied to "Trash".
- **gmail.com** - email is copied to "All".
- **mail.ru** - the only case where it goes to "Trash" after expunge.

I checked on Thunderbird logs and I saw that when user wants to "Delete" a message it just performs default IMAP "Move" operation. I tried to emulate it with "copy > set delete flag > expunge", but result wasn't the same...

- **gmail.com** - two copies of deleted email in "All" and "Trash" folders.
- **mail.ru** - two copies of deleted email in "Trash" folder.
- **aol.com** and **outlook.com** - haven't checked yet.

Seems like without "Move" all tries to delete or move a message to a different folder are useless...

Comment: The regular behavior is the one of aol.com and outlook.com. For mail.ru and gmail.com, you probably need to implement specific behavior of your app to move messages to Trash.

Answer (score 0):

Not all IMAP servers will have a `Trash` folder, since it does not exist in the IMAP RFC. (To find out which folders exist, use the `LIST` command.)
The world has changed a lot since the IMAP RFC was written, and many users expect a kind of `Trash` folder with restore/undelete capability. So servers and clients bend the RFC a little to emulate that behaviour. I would suggest that you make your behaviour configurable on your client (e.g. with a setting called something like "Move messages to trash when deleted?") This is what a lot of clients do (e.g. K9 mail)